# How to traverse the DOM to get to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a brain freeze trying to remember what the best way is to access the data attribute on an anchor tag when clicking a button that's not inside the tags container, could someone assist me on how I would do this, so if I click `.js-watchlist-add` I want to get the data-id of `.js-film-entry`:

JS

```
<div class="ctn">
    <a href="/movie/{{id}}" class="film-entry js-film-entry" data-id="{{id}}">
        <img src="{{poster}}" class="film-img">

        <div class="result-film-details">
            <h2 class="film-title">{{title}}</h2>
            <p class="film-release-date">Released {{releaseYear}}</p>

            <ul class="result-stats-tabs clearfix">
                <li>{{vote_average}} <span>Vote Average</span></li>
                <li>{{vote_count}} <span>Vote Count</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="cta-ctn">
        <button class="watchlist-add js-watchlist-add">Add to watchlist</button>
        <button class="watchlist-remove js-watchlist-remove">Remove from watchlist</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [closest(](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) to get the parent element and [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendant within parent.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6mt8L/)**

```
$(this).closest('.ctn').find('.js-film-entry').data('id');
```

Comment: missing a dot before js-film-entry

Answer (score 0):

Adil's answer is great,

Though it may be more efficient to use children versus find, to avoid traversing descendants.

```
$(this).closest('.ctn').children('.js-film-entry').data('id');
```

Just to give another DOM traversal example, you could also use:

```
 $(this).parent().siblings('.js-film-entry').data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) methods.

`$('.ctn').has(this).find('.js-film-entry')`

Comment: This might be a bit slower than Adil's suggestion though.